# How to update reportviewer in same view in asp mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rdlc

I want to make a asp mvc view  for reportview like 2 part:
part 1: option  -> buton submit
part 2: show reportview up to option (also refesh new rdlc and parameter...)

While research, i just found 3 solution for reportview in MVC: 
1/ Use Web User Control, or Aspx and insert it into view through @Html.RederPartial (i dont know how to pass parameter in this case too..)

2/ Use ReportViewer for MVC https://reportviewerformvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started

3/ Add Action for generate PDF, Excel, Word and Image File for Report Data
http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2013/09/microsoft-report-in-mvc-4.html

But both 3 solution will popup new page report when you press submit button. 
How can i reload it in same page with its option (filter) ?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

1) Take one parent view,within Parent view call partial view.

Parent View will have submit button and Partial view will have your Reportviewer mvc control. On button submit return partial view and if you can't able pass value to partial view then assign reportviwer data  to Viewdata or viewbag and use that viewbag to bind reportviewer in partial view.

Using above approach every time you can update reportviewer.